# Pontryagin dual and unitary dual of abelian group homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups, duality-theorems

Let $G$ be an abelian topological group, $G^\vee:=\{f\in\text{Hom}(G,\mathbb{T})\text{ continuous}\}$ its Pontryagin dual and $\widehat{G}:=\{\pi:G\to\text{U}(\mathcal{H})\text{ irreducible unitary representation}\}/_\cong$ its unitary dual. Using Schur's lemma, one can easily see that sending a unirrep $\pi:G\to\text{U}(\mathcal{H})$ to the character $G\to\mathbb{T}$, $g\mapsto\lambda_g$, where $\pi(g)=\lambda_g\text{id}_\mathcal{H}$, is a bijection $\varphi:\widehat{G}\to G^\vee$.

For Pontryagin duality to work, one equips $G^\vee$ with the compact-open topology and for Kirillov's orbit method to work, one equips $\widehat{G}$ with the Fell topology. **Is $\varphi$ a homeomorphism** then? If not, is it at least true if we restrict ourselves to locally compact groups or just $\mathbb{R}^n$? (For the case of $\mathbb{R}^n$ I think the continuity of $\varphi^{-1}$ is easy to see, since an isomorphism $\mathbb{R}^n\to(\mathbb{R}^n)^\vee$ is given by the exponential map.)

The definitions of the compact-open topology and the Fell topology seem to be quite similar, but I don't know how a proof of them being homeomorphic might look like. Any help or reference is very much appreciated!

Edit: The Fell topology on $\widehat{G}$ is generated by sets of the form $U_{K,\epsilon,x_1,...,x_n}(\pi):=\{\rho:G\to\text{U}(\mathcal{V})\ |\ \exists y_1,...,y_n\in\mathcal{V}:\ |\langle\pi(g)(x_i),x_j\rangle-\langle\rho(g)(y_i),y_j\rangle|<\epsilon\ \forall g\in K\ i,j=1,...,n\}$, where $K\subset G$ is compact, $\epsilon>0$, $x_1,...,x_n\in\mathcal{H}$ and $\pi$ as above.

Comment: If $G$ is abelian then all its irreducible representations are one dimensional. Thus the bijection you mentioned is quite obvious. I don't know Fell topology though.

Comment: @WhatsUp Added the definition of the Fell topology

Comment: I see. I think it's the same compact-open topology as the Pontryagin dual. Here $\pi$ is one dimensional, hence all the $x_i$ are scalar multiples of one basis element $x$, thus the inequality translates to $|\chi_\pi(g) - \chi_\rho(g)| < \epsilon$ up to a constant multiple of $\langle x, x\rangle$, where $\chi_\pi, \chi_\rho$ are the characters corresponding to $\pi, \rho$.

Comment: @WhatsUp Thanks a lot! Let me just write down what you meant: We can choose $x\in\mathcal{H}$, $y\in\mathcal{V}$ satisfying $\langle x,x\rangle=1=\langle y,y\rangle$ and we can write $x_i=a_ix$, since $\mathcal{H}$ is one-dimensional. Setting $y_i=a_iy$, the definition yields $a_ia_j|\chi_\pi(g)-\chi_\rho(g)|<\epsilon$ for all $g\in K$, i.e. convergence in the compact-open topology!

Comment: Yes, that's it!